# Print friends-list to console Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I go about printing to console a list of all my friends?
I'm hoping to be able to achieve this with the Discord.py library, hopefully someone here knows.

I currently get the error:
`for user in discord.ClientUser.friends: TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable`

Program:

```
token = ""
prefix = "::"

import discord
import asyncio
import codecs
import sys
import io
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

print ("waiting")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, self_bot=True)
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Friends")

@bot.command()
async def userlist(ctx):
    for user in discord.ClientUser.friends:
        print (user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)

bot.run(token, bot=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`discord.ClientUser`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#clientuser) is a class.  You want the `ClientUser` instance that represents your bots user account.  You can get this with [`bot.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.user), as `commands.Bot` is a subclass of `Client`

```
@bot.command()
async def userlist(ctx):
    for user in bot.user.friends:
        print (user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)
```

Answer (score -1):

From what the error states, `discord.ClientUser.friends` does not seem to have "unpackable" data.

For example,
`"abcdefg"` would iterate as "a", "b", "c", etc.
`[1, 2, 3, 4]` would iterate as 1, 2, 3, 4
The value stored in `discord.ClientUser.friends` appears to be an object and cannot be iterated.

Try doing `print discord.ClientUser.friends` to confirm this.

Answer (score -1):

`discord.ClientUser.friends` is not iterable - thus you can't run through its items in a for loop. I don't know that package, but try to see what type it is (you can do this like this - `print(type(discord.ClientUser.friends)))` and then see how to access the data in it.